# Why do I have error when inserting new data?

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I'm trying to override Voyager view "edit-add view" by adding one new input with the same controller.
But when I try to add new data I face this error.

> "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'Category_id' doesn't have
>   a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`,
>   `password`, `role_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (ali12345,
>   ali12345@ali12345.com,
>   $2y$10$qrHhwTFhnjluM7heNE.WCOwSbFIVsag4GWJzunZQGSLgdcXD2r21a, 3,
>   2019-04-25 22:45:45, 2019-04-25 22:45:45))"

I had tried to add fillable in the model but I didn't have a solution.

```php
protected $fillable = [
            'id',
            'role_id',
            'name',
            'email',
            'avatar',
            'password',
            'remember_token',
            'settings',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at',
            'Category_id'
        ];
```

Comment: `Category_id` is not in your query, but it has no default, so the software does not know what you want to be put in there. So, ever put it in the query, or set a default

Comment: I thought that but when I use dump and die function "dd()" I found the  request is 
 " +request: ParameterBag {#43 ▼
    #parameters: array:6 [▼
      "_token" => "6j5O6MGMJEGzj5R3QRBMLD0wrZi1kiHx0vzg446P"
      "name" => "ali12345"
      "email" => "ali12345@ali12345.com"
      "password" => "ali12345"
      "role_id" => "3"
      "Category_id" => "3"
    ]"

Comment: then how did you create the user?

Comment: I couldn't create any user.

Comment: I can't know why did I have this error !!

Comment: I know you couldn't, what I meant is, show me the block of code you are using to create the user. Ex: The `Controller` part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the issue is because you don't set the default value for **Category_id** in your table.

If you are sure that your request has the **Category_id** field, please ensure that you pass all the required fields when inserting a new record.

Let me give you some example of doing it with your case (Blocks of codes below should be somewhere in your *Controller*). Also I'll give you my favorite way to insert a new record.

Using Input facades:

```php
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User;

    $user->username = Input::get('role_id');
    $user->name = Input::get('name');
    $user->email = Input::get('email');
    $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
    $user->Category_id = Input::get('Category_id');
    $user->save();

    return Redirect::back();
}
```

This one is my favorite way to do it:

```php
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User;

    $data = $this->cleanUnfillableFields($request->all(), $user->getFillable());

    $user->create($data);

    return Redirect::back();
}

/**
* This removes/unsets fields that are not fillable from the model.
* This is the magic method where you should put in a separate class or a trait,
* so all controllers can share this method.
*
* @param array $data
* @param array $fillableFields
*
* @return array
*/
protected function cleanUnfillableFields(array $data, array $fillableFields): array
{
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
      if (! in_array($key, $fillableFields))
        unset($data[$key]);
    }

    return $data;
}
```

With my way above, you won't need to be hassle filling out each model's attribute and filtering out unnecessary fields anymore, as long as you set the fillable fields correctly and you have the required fields in your request.